# File upload request in SharePoint Website using JMeter proxy recording and load test fails

Tags: post, sharepoint, file-upload, jmeter, blazemeter

I have issues recording a file upload request using JMeter Proxy. The file could be selected with the browse option and on pressing the `SAVE` or `SUBMIT` button the page refreshes and goes to the initial state.

I'm working on a load test project on a **On-Premise SharePoint(v2013) Website** with the following conditions,

1. *Form-based authentication* - Login and session cookies are working
   correctly with JMeter.
2. Need to pass few dynamic variables like
   **__EVENTVALIDATION**, **__VIEWSTATE**, **__REQUESTDIGEST**, 
   **__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR** which needs to be extracted using a **RegEx 
   Extractor in JMeter** from every request and needs to be passed to 
   subsequent POST request as parameters.

As a workaround, I used **BlazeMeter Chrome Extension** to record the file upload requests and all the API calls could be recorded correctly. But has issues replaying it in JMeter. The file upload fails again even though all the requests pass.

1. All the file upload *POST* requests passes with a success response code 
   of **200** and gives the same HTML content as the response, while replaying it in JMeter, but the file never gets uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **absolutely** sure that you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in place, **correlation** is working fine, etc. in order to record the file upload request it should be just enough to put the file to JMeter's "bin" folder so [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) could locate it.

Make sure the file is present in the JMeter's "bin" folder during replay as well. Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more comprehensive explanation of the limitation.

---

If it doesn't help your JMeter configuration is still not correct. The common practice is capturing a request from a real browser and from JMeter using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). This way you will be able to inspect requests on a low level and identify the differences. Once you find out the cause - amend JMeter configuration so the request originating from JMeter would look exactly as the one which comes from the browser.

Comment: Finally, I decided to write down raw request body for the file upload POST request and pass in the file contents as a base64 encoded string. Thanks a lot for your response. I'll definitely try the way you mentioned next time.